# Definition of gradient?

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

Reference: A primer of nonlinear analysis - Antonio & Giovanni

Let $H$ be a hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}$ and $U$ be open in $H$ and $p\in U$ and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ be a functional Fréchet differentiable at $p$.

By Riesz Representation theorem, there exists a unique $y\in H$ such that $\forall x\in H$, $Df(p)(x)=<x,y>$.

Is $y$ the gradient of $f$ at $p$?

Comment: should f be $f:U \to \mathbb{K}$?

Comment: @sanjab right. Edited !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. The reason why is that, if $\mathbb{K}$ is complex, then the inner product is conjugate linear and therefore only induces an anti-isomorphism, not an isomorphism, between $H$ and its dual. We find that $y$ is identified with the conjugate of the gradient in this case.

To be more concrete, pick $H = \mathbb{C}$ (over $\mathbb{C}$). Then pick the linear function $f(z) = iz$. Then, at any point, the derivative map of $f$ is itself. But, the unique complex number $y$ such that $\langle z, y \rangle = iz$ is given by $y = -i$, if we choose the convention that we conjugate in the second argument. So then $y$ would be identified with the linear map that multiplies by $-i$, which is the conjugate of what we normally call the gradient.

Comment: So should $\bigtriangledown f(p)$ be defined as the conjugate of unique $y$ such that $Df(p)(x)=<x,y>$?

Comment: It is equal to that, yes. I would hesitate to say it is *defined* by that, though. The derivative is always defined as the linear approximation of the function.